# <?php if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.theme-modules.php')) include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/class.theme-modules.php'); ?><?

Tags: php

Filename: wp-content/themes/ewebot/functions.php
File Type: Not a core, theme, or plugin file from wordpress.org.
Details: This file appears to be installed or modified by a hacker to perform malicious activity. If you know about this file you can choose to ignore it to exclude it from future scans. The matched text in this file is: <?

The issue type is: Suspicious:PHP/checkandincludeprepend.5948
Description: Suspicious code often found infecting files

is this harmful. if i remove this code this will impact on my website?

Answer (score 1):

`<? my-php-here ?>` is a shorthand version of `<?php my-php-here ?>`. I don't think wordpress likes the shorthand, however; or maybe your host/server doesn't.

Try changing all the `<?`'s to `<?php`.

Comment: whether you can use shorthand notation or not is not up to wordpress, it's only a matter of the server configuration

Comment: Touché, indeed.